# Rails Carrierwave freezes app when uploading -- Will it do the same in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm not sure if this question suits SO but I've been testing out Carrierwave & tweaking it a little. I've noticed that when uploading a file to s3 using fog (this are small files, by the way..), my Rails app comes to a 'stand still' until the upload finishes processing.

---

I'm going to move all the processing to the background later on but this has me wondering:

Is it only like this in development?

Any overall suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have similar issues when using the default `webrick`, but when uploading in production with `apache` and `passenger`, I do not have these issues. You might try switching to `thin` in your development environment to see if that yields better results.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Best Ruby on Rails Architecture for Image Heavy App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16307493/best-ruby-on-rails-architecture-for-image-heavy-app/16341162#16341162), et al. My answer there is specifically about Heroku, but Heroku's merely a worst-case-scenario due to their many-small-servers architecture.