# Carrierwave Timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, carrierwave

I have used carrierwave for my users to upload files in my rails app. When a user uploads multiple files of size more than 400mb (approx.) they get a timeout error.

Note: I've hosted my app rails app on heroku.

Comment: That's because the temporary file is uploaded to heroku and then pushed to wherever you're storing it (like amazon).  Also, which web server you're using makes a difference, and if you're doing image processing this also drags out the time it takes to 'get' and 'process' and 'push' each upload.  To provide a solution though I'd need more information.  Where are you storing hte images?  Which web server are you using?  Are you processing image files (for thumbnails, and sizes)?  etc

Comment: I'm not processing any image. I'm using CSS for displaying images as thumbnails. I'm using ftp of bluehost for file storage.

Comment: Gotcha.  You'll have to roll your own solution, but using js uploads will take heroku out of the equation will be your best bet.  This solution is a good starting point. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16341162/1753596

Comment: For uploading large files you can process this in background with delayed job or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Uploading large files through Heroku is generally not recommended. They [limit the request to 30 seconds](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout#uploading-large-files), which would not be enough time for 400MB.

If you are open to using S3, Heroku provides a potential [Rails solution](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails) for that.

Comment: Timeout error is coming up after 10-20 minutes I guess. User told me that he can upload around 100 images (each image size 5-8 MB). But when uploading around 150 images, he get the timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

First solution is you can use refile gem.

> Reason is " Effortless direct uploads, even to S3 "

This gem is from Jonas Nicklas, who is behind Carrierwave gem

[refile](https://github.com/refile/refile)

[Blog on reason for refile gem](http://www.elabs.se/blog/68-refile-fixing-ruby-file-uploads)

Second solution

> move upload file into background jobs